# PHP MYSQL - Combine Query From Another Variable

Tags: php, mysql

May I know if I can combine queries from different variable or is there any other way. I want to insert `$query_1` to `$query_2`

**Example:**

```
$sql = "SELECT l_id from mlk";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $l_id[] = $row["l_id"];
     }
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

foreach($l_id as $row){
    $query_1= "(select count(*) from staff s where s.l_id = $row) as mlk_$row,";
}

$query_2= "SELECT mlk.lokasi,
//insert $query_1 here  
from mlk INNER JOIN staff WHERE staff.l_id=mlk.l_id GROUP BY mlk.lokasi";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

1. `mlk` is a table that stores staff working location
2. `$query_2` will display the Location Name and I also want to display the total number of staff on that particular location. eg, `Kuala Lumpur, 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the counting in the 2nd query:

```
SELECT mlk.lokasi, count(*) as no_of_staff 
from mlk
INNER JOIN staff on staff.l_id=mlk.l_id
GROUP BY mlk.lokasi
```

I also changed the implicit join into an explicit one by moving the join condition from the `where` clause to the `on` clause.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Shadow but will that count all the no. of staff. What if I want to count the no of staff base on location?  eg, `Kuala Lumpur | 10, Melaka | 5, Johor | 7`

Comment: Try it and you shall see :) Also you should read an sql tutorial on aggregate functions and group by...

Comment: It works great! Thanks for the info and advice. Will look through it.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join for this to show all the locations and then each location staff count.

SELECT mlk.lokasi, count(*) as no_of_staff 
from mlk
LEFT JOIN staff on staff.l_id=mlk.l_id
GROUP BY mlk.lokasi order by mlk.lokasi ASC